# How can I add a score to my game?

Tags: python, random

Just wondering how I could add a score in this game I made?
I don't understand how I can add a score that will add one every time someone gets a question right. I've tried many ways however I don't understand how I can do it, so I was wondering if anyone could help me so I can use this game for my computer science class at school.

```
import random
import time

name = input("What is your name? \n")
print(name, "Would you like to add or mulitply the questions?")

def main():
    num_1 = random.randint(1,100)
    num_2 = random.randint(1,100)
    answer = int(num_1) + int(num_2)
    answer_1 = int(num_1) * int(num_2)
    start = input("A - Add      B - Multiply      OR type STOP to get your score\n")
    start_n = start.upper()
    print(start_n)
    if start_n == "A":
        print("Add, " + str(num_1) + " and " + str(num_2))
        ans = input(">>> ")
        if int(ans) == int(answer):
            print("Well done, keep going!")
            main()
        else:
            print("Incorrect, but keep going!")
            print(answer)
            main()
    elif start_n == "B":
        print("Multiply, " + str(num_1) + " and " + str(num_2))
        ans = input(">>> ")
        if int(ans) == int(answer_1):
            print("Well done, keep going!")
            main()
        else:
            print("Incorrect, but keep going!")
            print(answer_1)
            main()
    elif start_n == "STOP":
        print(name + ", you got a score of - " + )
    else:
        print("Please only enter A or B")
        main()
main()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your current code the solution would be to pass the current score as an argument to `main()`, but...

You really shouldn't be calling the `main()` function recursively like that.
It's better to just use a while loop like this:

```
def main():
    score = 0
    while True:
        # ask the questions and stuff
        if correct:
            score += 1
        # do other stuff
        if stop_condition:
            break
    print(name, ', you got a score of -', score)
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @stranac's approach and propose you will following his advise.

However, if you add the following, it should also work:

Add

```
scrore = 0
```

before `def main():`.

Then, add the marked lines to the following code segment:

```
if int(ans) == int(answer):
            print("Well done, keep going!")
            global score    ## score is global
            score += 1      ## increment by one if answer is correct
            main()
```

And finally

```
print(name + ", you got a score of - "+ str(score) )
```